# Customized landingpages for categories

Tags: categories

When I click on a category now, it looks like..

> Category Archives: MyCategory
>
> first post
>
> second post
>
> third post..

I want to customize these landing pages for special categories, add text, pictures, html.

How do I do that, easiest way, w/o plugins.
There might be a file to be cloned, like content-category-mycategory.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), which gives you an overview of the different approaches.

You could create for each category an individual PHP file:

- either `category-{CATEGORY ID}.php`
- or `category-{CATEGORY SLUG}.php`.

Or you could use a single file `category.php` in which you define the output (as well as its layout, style etc.) according to the current category - again, either depending on its ID or its slug.

Here's a short example using the ID:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$cat_ID = $category[0]->cat_ID;
switch ($cat_ID) {
    case 'A':
        ...
        break;
    case 'B':
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Comment: Got stuck finding the Template Hierachy Link... Exactly what I was looking for, easy, fast. Thx

Comment: @Dan Yeah, unfortunately, the link is not that easy to be found as a search for _WordPress templates_, for instance, doesn't deliver what you want. You have to search for _template hierarchy_ instead - or just bookmark the page. ;)